# Linux "top -c" to show full command

Tags: linux, ubuntu, command-line, command-line-arguments

What parameter can help me to display the full command using `top -c`?

For example, I have one of the oupput from `top -c`

```
  5073 mysql     20   0  298m  12m 4668 S    0  0.0  29:27.46 /usr/sbin/mysqld --basedir=/usr --datadir=/var/lib/mysql --user=mysql --log-error=/var/log/mysql/mysqld.log --pid-file=/var/run/mysql/mysqld.pid -
```

There are more parameters after `--pid-file==/var/run/mysql/mysqld.pid`, but they are chopped off as the screen size. How can I make them visible?

Comment: Why do you ask? Why don't you use e.g. `ps auxww`, perhaps thru `watch` ?

Comment: You could use `htop` which supports scrolling.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch, goog question, I am not used to using "ps", but it is nice to know, thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**top** per se doesn't support wrapping, if i am correct. One way is you can increase your terminal width as follows.

```
export COLUMNS=_NO_YOU_DESIRE_
top

** then set update interval with 's _REFRESH_INTERVAL_'
** turn on command line display with 'c'
```

Comment: With zsh at least, this has undesirable side effects like shifting the right hand side prompt, and the initial position of the cursor.

Answer (score 6):

`htop` shows the full command. You can scroll to the right to see it all.

[image: htop screenshot]

http://hisham.hm/htop/

You can also rearrange, add and remove the columns to just show the information you are interested in. Press `h` inside top for details (or `man htop` in the terminal).

Answer (score 1):

What helped was using the `-O` option to move the command to the leftmost column and then `-f` to remove most of the other items. I was interested to see only the full command which was being run.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be an `-O` or `-f` argument to `top`.

Comment: Press `o` inside `top` to move columns left and right. Press `f` inside `top` to toggle columns.

Comment: After all the customisation, you may wish to press `W` for `top` to remember those settings for next time it starts.

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like `ps -eF > ps_out` to get a snapshot of your current processes, with all the command line arguments. Or use `htop` which supports scrolling.

*hth*

Answer (score -1):

top with cron.

```
crontab -l
*/5 * * * * ( echo; date -Is; top -b -n1 -c -w | head -n 12 ) >> ~/cpu_usage.log
```

-c display full command

-w prevent top for limiting line len to 80 char

-b batch mode

-n1 1 iteration